# JS: Convert xml data to dot array notation

Tags: javascript, xml, multidimensional-array, xml-parsing, nested

I have a xml file, it is list of products and repeating itself for number of products.
My problem is that i want to convert xml tags into dot notation javascript array.

Sample xml data: http://a.cdn.searchspring.net/help/feeds/searchspring.xml

Expected result:

```
[ 
  'Products.Product.Product_ID',
  'Products.Product.SKU',
  'Products.Product.Name' 
]
```

In this sample xml data accessing product name requires 2 nested level. But if xml data has 5 nested level it should must read up to 5 nested level. So it should depends on xml nested level.
Expected result for 5 nested level xml data

```
[ 
  'Products.Product.Categories.Category.Name',
  'Products.Product.Categories.Category.Description',
]
```

```
import * as parser from 'fast-xml-parser';
import * as fs from 'fs';
import * as path from 'path';

const xmlData = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve('format.xml'), 'utf8');
const tObj = parser.getTraversalObj(xmlData);
const jsonObjects = parser.convertToJson(tObj);

function walk(obj, key = '', response = []) {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(objKey => {
    key = key + objKey;
    if (!response.includes(key)) {
      response.push(key);
    }
    if (Object.keys(obj[objKey]).length > 0) {
      walk(obj[objKey], key, response);
    }
  });
  return response;
}

walk(jsonObjects);
```

When i try to run this code i got "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would take a check for a nested object at first and if no nested object, push the actual key.

```
function walk(obj, key = '', response = []) {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(objKey => {
        var newKey = key + (key && '.') + objKey;
        if (obj[objKey] && typeof obj[objKey] === 'object') {
            return walk(obj[objKey], newKey, response); // take nested object, not key
        }
        if (!response.includes(newKey)) { // do you expect duplicates?
            response.push(newKey);
        }
    });
    return response;
}
```

> When i try to run this code i got "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"

Right, you take a string (the key of an object) and any not empty string has properties, for each character one. And this string is handed over to the next recursion with the same result.

```js
console.log(Object.keys("foo"));
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, its working. But let assume if i have 10.000 items it loops up to finish it and taken 10 seconds to complete and it adds index number to dot notation.

```
[
  'products.product.0.name',
  'products.product.0.description',
  'products.product.1.name',
  'products.product.1.description',
  'products.product.2.name',
  'products.product.2.description',
]
```

How can i solve to non add index number ?

Comment: you could take a `Set` instead of an array for checking duplicates, which are impossible, because you can not have two same named properties in an object. so either omit this check or take a `Set`. for getting a different make up for the string, you could check for arrays and use a different style.